# Fork issue in apache with passenger in OS X High Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, macos-high-sierra

I decided to upgrade to OS x High sierra, and now I have an issue when starting the apps. I have this in the error_log of apache

```
objc[2019]: +[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[2019]: +[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
[Sun Jul 29 20:21:10.787536 2018] [core:notice] [pid 2004] AH00052: child pid 2019 exit signal Abort trap (6)
```

I'm running passenger 5.3.3 with ruby 2.5.0 and apache 2.4.33

I have saw a lot of things on the internet, but nothing works...

Help please

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's a known "issue" (that isn't an issue") and has known workarounds.

It's related to the fact that `fork`, if not performed properly, is fairly unsafe (consider that memory allocation might be happening in a different thread, resulting in a possible breakage for the memory allocator's locking system)...

Anyway, you can find more details about the issue [on this Puma issue thread](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1421) and [this blog post](https://blog.phusion.nl/2017/10/13/why-ruby-app-servers-break-on-macos-high-sierra-and-what-can-be-done-about-it/).

You can implement any of the suggested solutions, such as setting the environment variable `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY` to `YES`:

```
$ export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

Some servers, such as iodine, come with a solution out of the box (hard coded within their code base) while others assume an updated Ruby version.

I think Passenger should have a solution embedded in the newer versions, but I may be wrong.

Comment: thanks @Myst. The export is not working and I don't know why. I'm probably wrong in the way I set it. If I add the command in my .bash_profile file, is I'm ok?